# looking for a regex to match a specific pattern

Tags: regex, text, matching

I need to get rid of date formats in over 6000 lines of code. The format is always the same, but dates and times will vary including AM/PM.

This is the pattern

[10/6/17, 11:13:52 AM]

So far I used

```
.+?(?=[0-9])
```

which grabs numbers but now I am stuck. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Please provide example output for the sample string you provided.

Comment: There are plenty of answer for you :). Choose the one you prefer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(?i:(\[\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2},\s+\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s+[AP]M\]))
```

My regex is a full match with no capturing group and case insensitive. [Try it](https://regex101.com/r/GcPM8n/2). Then choose the answer you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how strict you need to be and the boundary conditions.
Something like

```
\[\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}, \d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \w{2}\]
```

should do it.

Btw, [regex101.com](https://regex101.com) is an awesome tool for debuging regexs

Answer (score 0):

This should match your dates :

```
\[\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}, \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2} [AP]M\]
```

Note that depending on the language you might need to escape the `/`.

[Try it here](https://regex101.com/r/wJgMDU/1).